# Is it possible to record ingame sound, save it and then have it on phone as regular song with c#?

Tags: c#, android, audio, unity-game-engine

i recently published game on play store that is about music making, it has drums, piano, loops... But i could not figure out if it is possible to record ingame sound, save it and than have it on phone as regular song with c#?
i Know Microphone().Record() , that is not what i need, i need a way to save, record music that is played at moment the user presses the piano key or drum pad...
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need another class and any sound framework to save song.
You can use NAudio: http://naudio.codeplex.com/
You need to:

- Every time when sound was played - you need to save it to array.
- Create Save() method or any other name you prefer.
- On Save() combile all sounds from array using framework and save them to file.

That's it.

Comment: thanks, but i do not have sounds, only buttons which they press in some order and that makes a beat sequence - one recorded sound. Now made that with unity for android, will this work with android and unity? Thank you very much for this answer, but i need something or script that works with unity android and will record in game sounds like fl studio...

Comment: Thank you very much, i figured out finally how to save something as wave file using N-Audio, but my problem is still ingame audio, its is very easy now using n-audio library to create wav file and fill it with sound created from microphone : Microphone.Record(); but my problem is if there is any solution for ingame sound?

Comment: When you play a sound hust append it to your wave file. I think you can't capture ALL game sounds.